# Regarding Full Text Search

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, custom-admin-grid

**I have created custom grid using UI component. My Full text searching showing error "Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.".**

> Below is my code:

```
<filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/search/search</item>
                    <item name="displayarea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_newlisting_listing.affiliate_newlisting_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_newlisting_listing.affiliate_newlisting_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_newlisting_listing.affiliate_newlisting_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
```

> what other things i have to do to make it working?

**Thanks**

Comment: I got the answer, I have gave Full Text Index in column in table and its working now.